# asp.net core web application error conenction to EF6 dbcontext

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using ef6 code first with existing databse. i generated model and dbcontext from existin model.

i am trying to use this dbcontext from my asp.net core 2.0 webapplication.

I am getting the errror as in the attachment.

Can anyone help?

My dbcontext in c# class library project is as below:

public partial class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext ()
        : base("name=DataContext ")
    {
    }

```
public virtual DbSet<Sample> Samples{ get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Sample>()
        .Property(e => e.Symbol)
        .IsUnicode(false);
}
```

}

Thanks[image]

I have the connection detail in asp.net coer appsetting.json file

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DataContext": "Data Source=....;Initial Catalog=...;User Id=...;Password=...;Integrated Security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For EF6, it reads connection string from **web.config** instead of **appsetting.json**, and there is no web.config in Asp.net Core by default.
If there is no need for you to target your project to **.net framework**, you could change **EF6** to **EF Core** which will read connectionstring from appsettings.json.
Demo Code:
ConfigureServices

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

ApplicationDbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Ignore(u => u.PhoneNumber);
    }
}
```

If you insist on using EF 6, you could try code below which passing the connectionstring.
ConfigureServices

```
services.AddScoped<SchoolContext>(_ => new SchoolContext(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Context

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext{
public SchoolContext(string connString) : base(connString)
{
}}
```